# python pandas data frame if else without iterating thought data frame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column to a df. The values of this new df will be dependent upon the values of the other columns. eg

```
dc = {'A':[0,9,4,5],'B':[6,0,10,12],'C':[1,3,15,18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dc)
   A   B   C
0  0   6   1
1  9   0   3
2  4  10  15
3  5  12  18
```

Now I want to add another column D whose values will depend on values of A,B,C.
So for example if was iterating through the df I would just do:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['A'] != 0 and row[B] !=0):
         row['D'] = (float(row['A'])/float(row['B']))*row['C']
    elif(row['C'] ==0 and row['A'] != 0 and row[B] ==0):
         row['D'] == 250.0
    else:
         row['D'] == 20.0
```

Is there a way to do this without the for loop or using where () or apply () functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`apply` should work well for you:

```
In [20]: def func(row):
            if (row == 0).all():
                return 250.0
            elif (row[['A', 'B']] != 0).all():
                return (float(row['A']) / row['B'] ) * row['C']
            else:
                return 20
       ....:     


In [21]: df['D'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
   A   B   C     D
0  0   6   1  20.0
1  9   0   3  20.0
2  4  10  15   6.0
3  5  12  18   7.5

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Great thanks ! Also would something like this work as well.
 
`code` elif (row[['A', 'B']] != 0 and row['C'] != None).all():

I have to check for None condition as well

Comment: You probably should convert those `None`s to `NaN`s. You'll get better performance since it will be a float dtype instead of column, and pandas operations are NaN aware.

Comment: Ohh ok Thanks!! so something like this ?

elif (row[['A', 'B']] != 0 and row['C'] != NaN).all()

Comment: It just depends on how you want to treat NaNs. If you return `NaN` when `row['C']` is `NaN`, then you won't even need this case, since `x * NaN` is `NaN`. If you want to return 0, you can do a `fillna(0)` after `apply`ing `fund`. Also, for various reasons `np.nan == np.nan` is *always* False, so your way wouldn't quite work. Pandas gives the `pd.isnull` function to check for NaNs.

Comment: got thanks. I just wanted to see if the syntax for correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

`.where` can be much faster than `.apply`, so if all you're doing is if/elses then I'd aim for `.where`. As you're returning scalars in some cases, `np.where` will be easier to use than pandas' own `.where`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['D'] = np.where((df.A!=0) & (df.B!=0), ((df.A/df.B)*df.C),
          np.where((df.C==0) & (df.A!=0) & (df.B==0), 250,
          20))

   A   B   C     D
0  0   6   1  20.0
1  9   0   3  20.0
2  4  10  15   6.0
3  5  12  18   7.5
```

For a tiny df like this, you wouldn't need to worry about speed. However, on a 10000 row df of randn, this is almost 2000 times faster than the `.apply` solution above: 3ms vs 5850ms. That said if speed isn't a concern, then .apply can often be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

here's a start:

```
df['D'] = np.nan
df['D'].loc[df[(df.A != 0) & (df.B != 0)].index] = df.A / df.B.astype(np.float) * df.C
```

edit, you should probably just go ahead and cast the whole thing to floats unless you really care about integers for some reason:

```
df = df.astype(np.float)
```

and then you don't have to constantly keep converting in call itself