# Function not being applied properly on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to the whole pandas and numpy world. I have experience with python but not on this side. I was trying to work with a data set and I found a issue that I am not able to explain. It will be great if someone with experience helps me to understand what is going wrong in it.

I have a CSV file with three fields. "Age", "Working Class" and "income". The headers were missing so I loaded the CSV in the following manner -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=False, header=None, names=["age", "workclass", "income"])
```

Now the data in the last column is in this format - "<=50K" or ">50K". I wanted to tranfer the data into either "0" or "1" based on the values above. So 0 for "<=50K" and 1 for ">50K". To accomplish that I wrote this line of code

```
def test_func(x):
    if x == "<=50K":
        return "0"
    else:
        return "1"

df['income'] = df['income'].apply(test_func)
```

This makes all the columns to become "1"! I did some printing inside test_func and it looks like x is having the right value and the type of x is of "str". I can not understand, in this case how come always the "else" part is getting executed and never the "if" part. What am I doing wrong?

It can be a very silly mistake that I am overlooking. I am not sure and any help will be great

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`astype`

```
df['income'] = df['income'].eq("<=50K").astype(int)
```

---

**Option 2**
`np.where`

```
df['income'] = np.where(df.income == "<=50K", 1, 0)
```

Comment: I used the second method because I discovered that my field values had spaces before them and that is why my original apply comparison was failing also. I could not find a way to strip the string using the first method. However for the seonnd `df['income'] = np.where(df.income.str.strip() == "<=50K", 1, 0)` works perfectly. Thanks everyone for your answers. That gave me a good lesson on pandas.

Answer (score 2):

I would just do:

```
df.loc[df['income']=='<=50K','income'] = 0
df.loc[df['income']!='<=50K','income'] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Alex's solution is a classic, but there is a built-in if/this function in numpy called np.where. I'm not super familiar with it, but it would look something like...

```
df['income'] = np.where((df['income']=='<=50K','income'), 1 ,0)
```

[Referenced np.where Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482304/python-pandas-data-frame-if-else-without-iterating-thought-data-frame)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ wasn't quite sure how to use it but had a feeling it was the function for the job! thanks for the providing the correct use.